# Vue bind class only on component load

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vue-component

i have a multi-section form UI, and each section can be collapsed. i want to apply classes ***on load*** such that if all the questions were already filled out in a section, that section is collapsed when the form component is loaded, but the class binding (alone - within each section i use `v-model`, so `v-once` is not an option) is not reactive (that is, when a user fills out all questions in the section, it does not automatically collapse)

is there a sensible way to achieve this?

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either computed property or methods to solve this.

With computed property:

```js
...
  computed: {
    collapsed() {
      return this.foo && this.bar
    }
  }
...
```

```html
<div class='content' :class='{ collapsed }'>
  ...
</div>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9L0eypkr/)

With methods:

```js
...
  methods: {
    computeCollapsed(inputs) {
      return inputs.every(x => x)
    }
  }
...
```

```html
<div class='content' :class='{ collapsed: computeCollapsed([foo, bar]) }'>
  ...
</div>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/38us0rcf/)

> In comparison, a method invocation will always run the function whenever a re-render happens.

Source [Computed Caching vs Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

If you only have a few sections and the number of sections if fixed, you should use computed property over methods.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a clone of the initial data and props that was not reactive, and using that to set up the initial status.